# Android crash happening sometime between onDestroy and onCreate when orientation changes

Tags: android, spinner, orientation-changes

Ive seen a lot of similar questions having different errors, most suggested to set `android:configChanges="orientation"` in the manifest, but thats not doing anything for me.

Basically I have a spinner that uses the dialog spinner mode, when it is open and the screen is rotated, I get this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: src.length=2 srcPos=0 dst.length=1 dstPos=0 length=2
at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeItem(WindowManagerImpl.java:655)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.finishRemoveViewLocked(WindowManagerImpl.java:431)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:395)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:170)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3376)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3556)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4961)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT: 
There are two scenarios where the user can get to this spinner, but only one of them is causing the crash. I have a view flipper which switches between two pages. The activity is for adding items to a list, or editing existing items. The first page is the list, the second is adding/editing an item. The user can either start with the list, then navigate to adding/editing an item. Or they can be automatically navigated to the second page from an outside the activity, either to add or edit an item. The spinner only shows up when adding items, and it only causes the crash when they are taken directly to the second page.

UPDATE: just tried disabling the save state information by adding `android:saveEnabled="false"` for that spinner in the xml file, but no luck. I even tried it on all the other spinners on the page in case it wasn't that specific one but still nothing.

UPDATE 2: I put log tags on start,stop,create, destroy,resume,saveinstancestate,and restoreinstancestate. It is correctly running Pause > SaveInstanceState > Stop >destroy, but then it crashes after onDestroy but before OnCreate starts.

Comment: Just a thought...  I think that the view is literally destroyed and recreated when you rotate it.  So whatever happens in OnCreate needs to run to make sure that thing is populated.  Otherwise, your index is empty.

Comment: Posting your oncreate would be helpful.

Comment: That's part of what I find so weird, that spinner is populated one of two ways, either in or after onResume depending on whether they start in the second view or not. Its crashing before it even gets to that point, but nothing in the OnCreate does anything with that spinner, other setting it to a variable when setting the content view.

Comment: Does removing configchanges="orientation" change the stack trace at all?  It looks like the system is trying to restore the old state of the activity after the rotation and it's unsuccessful.  That might be something better handled by manually saving the state of the spinner and recreating it in the oncreate event.

Comment: with and without configchanges="orientation" has the same stack trace. The most recent change I made to this page was manually saving some of the instance state information. But this spinner, even though its values are from the database, has the same values regardless of how the page was opened or what happens on the page. is there a way to not have it try to restore it from an old state?